# Transforming variables using .apply()

Tags: python, mapping

The unique values of Shell are 1, 2 and 3. Write a function that changes these values 1, 2 3 to “one”, “two”, “three” respectively. Apply the function to the Shelf column using the .apply() method of the DataFrame to transform the values 1, 2, 3 to “one”, “two”, “three” respectively. Do not create an extra column but override the existing Shell column. The new Shell column should now have unique values “one”, “two”, “three”.

The dataframe is in the picture below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you future question always add a sample data in format that is easy to be copied. Also write what have you tried to achieve your goal and what part causes you a problem. Because no one will give you the answer on more advanced topic and you will learn nothing hence fail on your next task.

You could do like that:

```py
values_map = {
    '1': 'one',
    '2': 'two',
    '3': 'three'
}
df['Shelf'] = df['Shelf'].apply(lambda x: values_map[x])
```

Comment: If there is something that you do not understand let me know in this comment section